# Can I access values generated by google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, googlevis

Currently I pass variables to the api like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 mobileNav();
 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

 // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 //Callback that creates and populates a data table,
 // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
 // draws it.
 function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Attendance');
  data.addRows([
    ['Present', <?php echo $present; ?>],
    ['Absent', <?php echo $absent; ?>],
    ['Directed Study', <?php echo $directed; ?>],
    ['Medical Certificate', <?php echo $medical; ?>],
    ['Self Certificate', <?php echo $selfcert; ?>],
    ['Authorised Absence', <?php echo $authorised; ?>],
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'Your Attendance'};


  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new      google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

I get the results and everything is good. I would like to access the % values generated by the pie chart. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access on your values generated by your pie chart , you need to retrieve data on your dataTable().

You need to use getFormattedValue method.

Documentation :
DataTable API : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

Method : getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)

Comment: All this does is return the same data that is put into the chart. i.e. 2 where I am looking for something like '13%'

Comment: Are you tested :  data.getNumberOfRows() ?

Comment: below is the results from the following functions written to log.

'data.getNumberOfRows() -> 6 | 
data.getNumberOfColumns() -> 2 |
console.log(data.getFormattedValue(1,0));  -> Absent |
console.log(data.getFormattedValue(1,1));  -> 2'